# disadvantages to using ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

using Django `rest-auth` and `allauth`, using a rest api. I have `ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET=True.` 
the documentation it gave a warning about this. Are there any major disadvantages to this? this method seems to be perfect for me and i would like to know what trouble this could cause in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it has more to do with what a `GET` request suppose to do. In many documenations such as [**`MDN web docs`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) or [**`Wikipedia`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Affecting_server_state) it is mentioned that a `GET` request should not create a side effect on the server. Meaning making a `GET` request should not change anything in server side, it should only be used for retrieving data.

So, I think you should consider this approach (from [**`documentation`**](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration)):

> To avoid requiring user interaction, consider using POST via
>   Javascript in your email confirmation template as an alternative to
>   setting this to True.